# why Environment.getExternalStorageState() case NullPointException in Android

Tags: java, android

my code

```
private static String getSDCardPath() {
    boolean sdCardExist = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState());
    if (sdCardExist) {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState(Environment.java:602)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115385/npe-on-environment-getexternalstoragestate

Comment: My code is Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) and still case NPE